# ссылка на вывод пользователей определенной роли laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

подскажите, как сформировать ссылки, чтобы обработать их одним методом и вывести по категориям ролей?

```
<a href="{{ url('manager/users') }}">Преподаватели</a>
<a href="{{ url('manager/users') }}">Ученики</a>
```

Comment: Можете передавать get параметр. `http://site.com/manager/users?role=teachers`, Ну либо изменить роут и добавить `site.com/manager/users/{role}`..

Comment: а скажите лучше использовать готовую библиотеку создания ролей или самому создавать через связи с таблицей users?

Comment: я про вот это composer require spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: Можно и самому.  Если хотите - используйте, тут строгих правил нету..  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#middleware-parameters

Comment: а это уже готовое решение? как мне забить список и таблицу под роли?

Comment: Нет, это не готовое решение. В моделе пользователя надо создать метод для проверки роли. Ну а дальше, по докумментации..

Comment: как я понял:
создать модель с миграцией php artisan make:model RolesUser -m, создать поля и связать с таблицей пользователи?

Comment: у меня есть таблица users(id,name,email,password), users_attributes(user_id,username,photo ...) над таблицей ролей я пока в раздумье, как организовать это все, при переходе по manager/users/{role} я вывожу пользователя определенной роли

Comment: Ну если сильно не заморачиваться, то можно сделать таблицу `roles (id, user_id, role)` и тогда уже в контроллере выводить пользователей с такой то ролью из таблицы.

Comment: а как в том примере что вы выслали, чтобы было через middleware?

Comment: Да там уже чисто для проверки: может ли конкретная роль исполнять какой-то метод или т.д., немного не то, что надо

Comment: например создал я модель Rolesи например в роуте мне нужно проверить роль Route::put('post/{id}', function ($id) {})->middleware('role:editor'); как в таком случае быть?

Comment: В таком случаи нужно создать middleware CheckRole точно такую же, как в том примере, что я кинул раньше. Потом в моделе `User` создать метод `hasRole($role) { ... }`, где написать следующее: `return boolval(Auth::user()->role === $role);` (это к примеру, может и можно лучше оформить). Ну и если, пользователь имеет роль `editor`, то он сможет редактировать пост, иначе просто будет редиректить на страницу, которую Вы укажете в middleware

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете передавать в котроллер GET парамтер - Роль пользователя.
И уже по ним фильтровать и выводить. Что-то типа:

{{url('manager/users/{role}')}}